# windowsdriver.common.targets missing

Tags: build, sdk, visual-studio-2017, wdk

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to develop Windows drivers. But when building the project, It returns the following error:

```
MSB4019 The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. libxdma D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0\Toolset.targets
```

I've got windows SDK (10.0.10586.212 & 10.0.17134.12) and WDK (10.0.15063.0 & 10.0.16299.15) installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install WDK that matches SDK version. In your case if you install WDK 10.0.10586.XXX/10.0.17134.XXX and create a driver project which has "Windows SDK Version" set to one of those version, this issue should go away.